# Apache Beam - Flink Container Docker Issue (java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2,)

Tags: docker, apache-beam

I am processing a Kafka stream with Apache Beam by running the Beam Flink container they provide.

`docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.13_job_server:latest`

After setting up the container I run a script using `python main.py`

```
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=PortableRunner",
        "--job_endpoint=localhost:8099",
        "--environment_type=LOOPBACK",
    ])

    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    result = (
        pipeline
        | "Read from kafka" >> ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={
                "bootstrap.servers": 'localhost:9092',
            },
            topics=['demo'],
            expansion_service='localhost:8097',
        )

        | beam.Map(print)
    )

    pipeline.run()
```

When doing so the Beam Flink container receives the pipeline submission but runs into the following error during execution:

```
Jul 15, 2021 6:24:50 PM org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution transitionState
INFO: Source: Impulse (1/1) (b8ee3d07bb3fba0ce7b8c6e8f1055168) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
Jul 15, 2021 6:24:50 PM org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.DockerCommand runImage
WARNING: Unable to pull docker image apache/beam_java8_sdk:2.31.0, cause: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
Jul 15, 2021 6:24:50 PM org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task transitionState
WARNING: [3]Read from kafka/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaSDF/{ParDo(GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor), KafkaIO.ReadSourceDescriptors} (1/2)#0 (ede2e66e82e968a1df246f14a9c7e1f6) switched from INITIALIZING to FAILED with failure cause: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:38)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:202)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.ExecutableStageDoFnOperator.open(ExecutableStageDoFnOperator.java:243)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:437)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:582)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:759)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Are there any dependencies on running this container?

Comment: Python Kafka transforms are cross-language transforms that are implemented in Java. These currently require Docker and Java in the local system to start the pipeline.

Comment: @chamikara I'm also facing the same issue. I am running Flink on Kubernetes cluster. So is it okay to run docker container within Flink taskmanager container? If there is any other way to do this please point me to any docs or article links.

Answer (score -1):

I had "python" instead of "docker", the problem was because of I was working with `python3`, for my case the solution was with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This is not an answer for the question.